# Multiple ble advertisements in a UWP app

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I am trying to publish multiple ble advertisements in a UWP app in c#. I can add 2 manufactor data to one publisher and those will be transmitted. However if I want to publish more the data is not possible. Is this even possible?

Sample code so far:

```
var publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();
publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("Test");
publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("AnotherTest");
publisher.start();

BluetoothLEManufacturerData CreateData(string data)
{
    var dataWriter = new DataWriter();
    dataWriter.WriteInt32(data.Length);
    dataWriter.WriteString(data);

    return new BluetoothLEManufacturerData(0xFFFE, dataWriter.DetachBuffer());
}
```

Tried to add another manufactor data, but I get an exception
Tried multiple bluetooth adapters but windows don't seem to start the second adapter.
Also tried multiple Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher but that also does not do the trick

Answer (score 2):

We can put multiple manufacturer data in one BluetoothLE Advertisement. However, please note that the max length of an advertisement payload is **31 bytes**.

Ref **ADVERTISING AND SCAN RESPONSE DATA FORMAT** (BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.0 [Vol 3] Page 375 )

> The format of Advertising data and Scan Response data is shown in Figure
>   11.1. The data consists of a significant part and a non-significant part. The
>   significant part contains a sequence of AD structures. Each AD structure shall
>   have a Length field of one octet, which contains the Length value, and a Data
>   field of Length octets. The first octet of the Data field contains the AD type field. The content of the remaining Length - 1 octet in the Data field depends on the value of the AD type field and is called the AD data. The non-significant part extends the Advertising and Scan Response data when necessary and shall
>   contain all-zero octets. 
>   [image]

[BluetoothLEManufacturerData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothlemanufacturerdata) is one of these AD structures which AD Type is [`0xFF`](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile).
[image]

For your first manufacturer data `CreateData("Test")`, its length is 1 (Lenght) + 1 (Type) + 2 (Company Id) + 8 (Your specific data), which is 12 bytes. And for the second manufacturer data, its length is 19 (1+1+2+15) bytes. With these two manufacturer data, the advertisement payload has already been 31 bytes. That's why you get an exception, when you try to add another manufacturer data. Actually, if you add one character in your date, for example using `CreateData("Test=")` instead of `CreateData("Test")`, you will also get the `Invalid advertisement payload detected` error.

So please **make sure that the buffer length can fit within an advertisement payload**. You can put multiple manufacturer data as long as its length is less than 31 bytes.

```
var publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();
publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("T"));
publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("A"));
publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("S")); 
publisher.start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know a way to broadcast multiple advertisment payload with a payload > 31 bytes or in parallel?

Comment: @user7895198 [Bluetooth.Advertisement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.aspx) is used for Bluetooth Low Energy Advertisement beacons. It's not designed to broadcast large amount of data. I'm not sure what's your real scenario is. I'd suggest you ask a new question with your real scenario. Then others may give you some useful suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like mentioned in the original post but maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to be able to publish multiple BLE advertisements at the same time from one UWP app.

Comment: @user7895198 If you want to send multiple BLE advertisements, you can use multiple `BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher`s. However, please note there is no guarantee for the order of the received advertisement.