UWP Bluetooth: Value does not fall within the expected range
I am trying to implement a simple service on Windows, using this sample:
https://github.com/grishka/NearDrop/issues/154
However, there are 2 issues:

While the code runs, I don't actually see any new device being advertised
Whenever I try to set the advertisement name e.g. advertisement.LocalName = "MyDevice", the publisher.start() code fails with Value does not fall within the expected range
The serviceData bytes - I don't know what to make of it. I looked in the bluetooth specs, read the SDK specs, but cannot figure out the format of this byte array.

Any idea how to set this up correctly so that I can advertise my service UUID and a custom local name?

First at all: you can not change local device name. It is always must be as your PC name. Second: you must advertise Service UUID16 Data advertisement. Based on the link it is simple invalid data added to the advertising payload. Refer to Bluetooth spec. advertisement format and add correct packet ID and length bytes.


Are you referring to the AD spec? i.e. {length,  {adType, data}} as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517634/multiple-ble-advertisements-in-a-uwp-app
Then how do I set the name of the bluetooth device that appears in the scanners?



Yes. 2 Change name in Bluetooth adapter settings.

